# How to prove the dual optimal solutions are bounded

Tags: optimization

Consider following optimization problem:
\begin{equation} \label{eqn:primal}
\begin{aligned}
\min_{x\in \mathcal{X}} f_p(x)\\
\text{s.t.}~g(x)\leq 0\\
h(x) = 0
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
with non-empty domain $\mathcal{X}$ and finite optimal value $p^*$. The Lagrange dual problem as
\begin{equation} \label{eqn:dual}
\begin{aligned}
\max_{\lambda,\eta} f_d(\lambda,\eta)\\
\text{s.t.}~\lambda\geq 0\\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
f_d(\lambda,\eta) := \inf_{x\in\mathcal{X}} f_p(x) + \lambda^{\top} g(x) + \eta^{\top} h(x).
\end{equation}
If functions $f_p(x)$, $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ are all convex, there exists a vector $\tilde{x}\in\mathrm{relint}(\mathcal{X})$, which makes the inequality constraints strictly feasible (Slater's Condition), such that
\begin{equation*}
g(\tilde{x}) < 0\qquad \text{and} \qquad h(\tilde{x}) = 0.
\end{equation*}

Since the Strong Duality holds, I am able to prove that dual optimal $\lambda^*\in\Re^m$ is bounded using the Slater's Condition, such that
\begin{equation*}
0\leq \sum_{k=1}^m \lambda^*_k \leq \frac{d^* - f_p(\tilde{x})}{\max_{1\leq k\leq m} g_k(\tilde{x}) } \leq \infty,
\end{equation*}
where $d^*$ is the dual optimal value.

My Question is: Is it possible to prove that dual optimal $\eta^*\in\Re^n$ is bounded?

Comment: Your proof for $\lambda$ is not valid: what if $g_k(\tilde{x})=0$? Is there a reason you write 'max' instead of 'sup' for the dual?

Comment: Slater condition holds, so g(tilde(x))<0

Comment: Slater condition says something about a feasible point, but nothing about the optimal solution

Comment: How would you show for $\lambda$ and what prevents this proof from being extended to $\eta$?

Comment: \begin{equation*}
d^* = \inf_{x\in\mathcal{X}} f_p(x) + \lambda^{*\top} g(x) + \eta^{*\top} h(x) \leq f_p(\tilde{x}) + \lambda^{*\top} g(\tilde{x}) \leq f_p(\tilde{x})  + \alpha \sum_{k=1}^m \lambda_k^*,
\end{equation*}
where 
\begin{equation*}
\alpha := \max_{1\leq k\leq m} g_k(\tilde{x}) < 0. 
\end{equation*}
Therefore, dual feasibility ensures that
\begin{equation*}
0\leq \sum_{k=1}^m \lambda^*_k \leq \frac{d^* - f_p(\tilde{x})}{\alpha} \leq \infty.
\end{equation*}